# Is there a way to review WordPress posts before importing?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I am rebooting my blog. I have several hundred posts from my old WordPress blog. Some of these I want to keep, others I want to purge. Is there a desktop app (preferably) or web-based interface that will take my exported WordPress XML file and let me peruse each post before letting me decide which posts to keep and re-export as an XML file?

Comment: Why not upload the posts to a blank WordPress blog, go through each post and remove what you don't need, and then export it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Tom suggested having not found a better solution. Thanks.